# Dynamically adding a ViewGroup to an active Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking to insert items into lists in the View below when any of the add buttons are clicked. What I'd like is to display all the information that is being collected, but I'm not really sure how to add a ViewGroup programatically and insert it into the ConstraintLayout in the correct locations while bumping all the corresponding items below.

I've updated the button code and now I'm running into a mess of other problems, currently when the button is clicked a TextView that reads "Name: " appears and is properly inserted into the Layout, but it seems that something isn't going right when I set the id for textView name and it either isn't being recorded or I'm not using the methods correctly.

Button Code

```
protected void addWeap(View view)
{
    int id = 0;
    int weapons = 0;
    String weaponAdder = "";
    int weaponPointer = 0;

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.conLayout);
    EditText weapN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weapName);
    EditText weapAB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weapattbns);
    EditText weapDMG = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weapDmg);
    EditText weapInfo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weapInfo);
    TextView proItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proItem);
    String weapName = "";
    String weapAttBns = "";
    String weapdmg = "";
    String weapinfo = "";
    weapName += weapN.getText();
    weapAttBns += weapAB.getText();
    weapdmg += weapDMG.getText();
    weapinfo += weapInfo.getText();

    weapons++;
    weaponAdder += weapName + "|";
    weaponAdder += weapAttBns + "|";
    weaponAdder += weapdmg + "|";
    weaponAdder += weapinfo + "|";

    weapN.getText().clear();
    weapAB.getText().clear();
    weapDMG.getText().clear();
    weapInfo.getText().clear();

    TextView name = new TextView(this);
    params.topToBottom = weaponPointer;
    params.leftToLeft = R.id.parent;
    name.setText(R.string.namePrint);
    name.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    name.setLayoutParams(params);
    name.setPadding(8,8,0,0);
    name.setId(id);
    id++;
    weaponPointer = id;
    constraintLayout.addView(name);


    params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView weaponName = new TextView(this);
    params.baselineToBaseline = id;
    params.leftToRight = id;
    params.rightToRight = R.id.parent;
    weaponName.setText(weapName);
    weaponName.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    weaponName.setLayoutParams(params);
    weaponName.setPadding(8,8,8,0);
    constraintLayout.addView(weaponName);


    params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftToLeft = R.id.parent;
    params.rightToRight = R.id.parent;
    params.topToBottom = id;
    proItem.setPadding(8,8,8,0);
    proItem.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

[Pre-Button Push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDQjM.png)

[Post-Button Push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRMlG.png)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bumping", but all `ViewGroup` objects have `addView` method. However, you never create a view object in the java code here

Comment: I updated the post with what I've changed so far.

Comment: It's not clear what you've changed. If the code is updated, you can replace it all

Comment: If you'd like some assistance, try to get a [mcve] in your question that we can reproduce on our own.

Comment: I've updated the post to try and narrow focus in on the issues I'm seeing, and my thoughts as to what might be causing them.

Comment: Everytime you click on the button, you set ID to zero, then add 1. Everytime you're going to find or reference a view in the click event, it'll always be the first one. There should be a method `View.generateViewId()` on API 17+, otherwise, you'll need to manage your ID values differently. It also must be a positive integer, but you've set it at 0 for the first TextView

Comment: Thanks that helped alot and using those I was able to build a solution.